# Need script FOR loop in shell or perl

Tags: shell, perl

I am looking for loop condition which would help me to run below commmand.

mccli backup show --name=abc.com

name=server_name

I dont want to run the command everytime with changing server name.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Unix Bash shell, the following command will do what you want (assuming servers abc.com, xyz.com, server3.com):

```
for server in abc.com xyz.com server3.com; 
    do mccli backup show --name=$server; 
done
```